# Private property mapping with fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I am getting exception mapping a private property.This is the situation:
I have this in Entity.cs: 
privat int m_Inactive;

and in EntityMap.cs I have :

```
Map(x => Reveal.Property<Entity>("m_Inactive")).ColumnName.("INACTIVE");
```

But I get this error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown 
by 
the target of an invocation. --->  System.ArgumentException: Not a member access
```

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you follow the [examples on the wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties) you'll see that you're supposed to use `Map(Reveal.Member<YourEntity>("m_Inactive"))`.

Comment: The link is outdated. The updated one is:
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties
and
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Mapping_a_collection_that_uses_a_private_backing_field

Comment: I've recently moved servers and had forgot to re-create the url redirects. Thanks for reminding me! Both the old and the new link are working now.

Comment: Links broken again, use this link: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in the latest version you're supposed to use Reveal.Member since Reveal.Property is obsolete:

```
Map(Reveal.Member<YourEntity>("m_Inactive"))
```

Oh, and sort of a "duh" but you'll need to make sure you include FluentNHibernate:

```
using FluentNHibernate;
```

And another "duh" but this will work with **protected** members as well as **private**.