# using fluent nhibernate, is there anyway to have a private property mapped

Tags: c#, nhibernate

i have a field that i want to map as it links to a column in the database but i don't want any external class to access this field directly from my code (its only used in private calculations).

is this possible to have a field that i can map but it private using fluent nhibernate??

Comment: You could also set your field to have `protected` accessors then external classes can't see or set it and no need to twist your Fluent mapping.

Comment: @ChrisAnnODell - wouldn't it have to be internal?  How will the mapping class see it if it's only protected?

Comment: The mapping class only uses the properties to define the mapping and does not attempt to access them.  [`Internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.80).aspx) would limit the property to objects defined in the same assembly, but nHibernate will inherit from the mapped class to create proxy so [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.71).aspx) is what you need to allow it to set the values from your repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use the Reveal.Member static methods to map a private or hidden property

```
Map(Reveal.Member<string>("privateProperty"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](https://github.com/nhibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties) is what you're looking for.

> **Fluent mapping private properties**
>
> There’s been a point of contention for
> some users of Fluent NHibernate since
> the beginning, and that’s the lack of
> a method of mapping private and
> protected properties on their domain
> entities.
>
> The issue stems from our use of lambda
> expressions for static reflection of
> your entities, one of the appealing
> properties of Fluent NHibernate; by
> utilising expressions we’re able to
> protect your mappings from refactoring
> side-effects. However, lambda
> expressions can only reference
> properties that are public on an
> object, so that makes it difficult to
> use against protected or private
> properties.
>
> None of the solutions we have are
> ideal, we’ll be the first to admit
> that; but considering Fluent
> NHibernate was never designed to
> support these situations, and the
> limitations C# imposes on us, we’ve
> got some pretty reasonable choices.
> Each option comes with its own
> compromises, so it’s important you
> pick the method that has the
> compromises you’re more willing to
> accept; I’ll outline the pros and cons
> of each approach.

Comment: so is everything on this article possible today or is this a proposal listing options to the community.  Does it support it today or not??

Comment: It appears all the techniques on that page can be used today. What made you question whether you could implement those patterns today?

Answer (score 0):

This an example from my project. My domain classes have only public properties. No setters.
The object is created through the constructor and data is manipulated using methods.

**Entity**

```
public class User: Entity
{
    private string _openid;
    private string _email;
    private string _username;
    private int roleid;

    // needed for mapping
    protected User() { }

    // your normal constructor
    public User(string openid)
    {
        Validator.NotNull(string openid, "openid is required.");
        _openid = openid;
    }

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
    }

    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
    }

    public string Openid
    {
        get { return _openid; }
    }

   // Here are some methods
   // ... 
}
```

**Mapping Class**

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
    {
        public UserMap()
        {
            Table("user");

            // Reveal private attributes and map them
            Id(Reveal.Member<User>("_id")).Column("id");
            Map(Reveal.Member<User>("_username")).Column("username");
            Map(Reveal.Member<User>("_openid")).Column("openid_claimed_identifier");
            Map(Reveal.Member<User>("_email")).Column("email");

            // You need to create this mapping if you want to query using linq, 
            //see UserRepository below
            Map(x => x.Id, "id").ReadOnly();
            Map(x => x.Email, "email").ReadOnly();
            Map(x => x.Username, "username").ReadOnly();
            Map(x => x.Openid, "openid_claimed_identifier").ReadOnly();
        }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(ISession session)
           : base(session)
        {
        }

        public User find_user_by_openid(string openid_claimed)
        {
            return base.FindBy(x => x.Openid == openid_claimed);
        }

        public User find_user_by_id(int id)
        {
            return base.FindBy(x => x.Id == id);
        }        

    }
```

One important thing to remember: **do not use underscores within attribute names**. Such as:

```
   public class User: Entity
    {
        //...
        private int role_id;
    }
```

Fluent NHibernate does not like it when you use a particular attribute to map **References**.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least minimize the harm of exposing internal structure by leaving only getters public:

```
public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
```