# How to map a single datetime column to two seperate datetime properties in a model

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

If I have an object with a DateTime property is it possible to map the Date and the Time to seperate properties in the same object? I.e An object with a StartDateTime, StartDate and StartTime where StartDateTime exists as a column in the database and StartDate and StartTime simply reference the different parts of the StartDateTime column.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that trick here would be:

1. map one property to that column. It could be hidden for other parts of your Model, even protected *(e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5432380/1679310))*
2. create two virtual *(I mean un-mapped properties)*  public properties accessing and setting that mapped value.

For example, very similar scenario I use for mapping a `version`. So while this would be the mapping:

```
<version name="Timestamp" generated="always" unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">
  <column name="RowVersion" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp"/>
</version>
```

It is working with `byte[]` which is hard to send to UI - Client. So this this would be the Domain Entity representation.

```
protected virtual byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }

public virtual string Version
{
    get { return Timestamp.IsEmpty() ? null : Convert.ToBase64String(Timestamp); }
    set { Timestamp = value.IsEmpty() ? null : Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
}
```

Having that in place, we can send the `version` to client as a `string`... and get it back...

*NOTE: I would map the DB column to public property. It makes it easier to use that property in `QueryOver` queries... at least getter could be public*